# Access VBA single quote in name causes syntax error

Tags: vba

I have a form with a list of supplier names, when I click a button with the following code attached;

```
Private Sub CmdView_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdView_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "FrmSuppliers"

    stLinkCriteria = "[SupplierName]=" & "'" & Me![SupplierName] & "'"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_CmdView_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_CmdView_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdView_Click

End Sub
```

A form with their information opens, however, I have one supplier who has an apostrophe in their name e.g. O'Tooles, and when I click the button for them I get the error.

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
'[SupplierName]='O'Tooles''.
```

Is there a way to change the code to account for apostrophes?

Comment: try using chr(39)  instead of the apostrophe.

Comment: @SivaprasathV I don't understand how this would work.

Comment: chr(39) is the character constant for apostrophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use single-quotes as a string delimiter, use double quotes instead (they just need to be escaped with an extra `"`:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[SupplierName]=" & """" & Me![SupplierName] & """"
```